# lodash too much recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, lodash

We have a very old application which we have to maintain as part of our shop. The application is running on eagle clients and is bound to Firefox version 17, I know what you think now WTF??? Me too :)

But since the last release from our shop which is based on React we get the error too much recursion but this happens only in Firefox, Chrome works absolutely fine. The only thing I found out that it is related to lodash but I can't find any solution only. So I would like to ask whether someone of you had a similar or even the same issue?

The Code snippet which is marked by Firefox 17 Inspector as the error code is this one [Firefox inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjSUd.png)

Comment: Could you provide us stacktrace and lodash version?

Comment: Lodash version is 4.17.15

Comment: And for the stacktracke i only have the screenshot I added in my question where the line which is marked blue is the one who throws the error. I added a console log there and opened it in my chrome browser where the sourcemap is used and it said thath its from one of the lodash js files

Comment: What I just found out that in Firefox 16 everything works

Comment: Can't find following line of code in lodash. This function doesnt do anything special apart from checking if `e` is an object which inherits from object prototype. Can you put breakpoint in there and see the stacktrace?